# How to use a com_content extension category on other Joomla4 Component?

Tags: joomla-extensions, joomla4

i was learn and build custom Joomla 4 component, named com_content2.
the source is similar with com_content Joomla component,

**Problem**
in edit layout
url
Joomla/adm/index.php?option=com_content2&view=article&layout=edit&id=2
i can't get the category form based on com_content extension
the default use category based on com_content2.

**Trial error**
i have try to copy 2 file on adm/com/com_categories/src/field to adm/com/com_content2/src/field but its still not working..

**The Goal**
iwant have a category dropdown form based on com_content extension.
my component will use a same category with com_content extension?

Comment: Its completely done by myself